# applying specific css to added edges in cytoscape edgehandles

Tags: cytoscape.js, edges

I want to add specific CSS (for instance a specific line-color) to certain, but all, edges added with cytoscape.js-edgehandles.js.

I used to cy.edges(selector) command to apply a specific line-color (red) to the edges with source ('I'). But this only works for already existing edges, but not for added edges.

```
$('#cy').cytoscape({
```

ready: function(){

```
window.cy = this;

cy.edges("[source='I']").addClass('red');
```

},

```
elements: {
                    nodes: [
                        { data: { id: 'I', name: 'Irlande' } },
                        { data: { id: 'H', name: 'Pays-Bas' } },
                        { data: { id: 'F', name: 'France' } },
                        { data: { id: 'L', name: 'Luxembourg' } }
                    ],
                    edges: [

                        { data: { source: 'I', target: 'F' } },

                        { data: { source: 'I', target: 'H' } }
                        { data: { source: 'I', target: 'L' } },
                        { data: { source: 'H', target: 'I' } },
                        { data: { source: 'H', target: 'F' } },
                        { data: { source: 'F', target: 'I' } },
                        { data: { source: 'F', target: 'H' } },
                        { data: { source: 'F', target: 'L' } },
                        { data: { source: 'L', target: 'I' } }

                    ]

                },
```

});

This leads me to a couple of related questions:

Do the added edges merge with the existing edges? 
If the answer is 'no', how can I get them to merge with edges[]?

The relevant code in cytoscape.js-edgehandles.js is :

var edge = cy.add($.extend( true, 
            {
                group: 'edges',
                data: 
                {
                  source: source.id(),
                  target: target.id()
                }
             }, options().edgeParams(source, target, 0))).addClass(classes);

```
          added = added.add( edge );

          break;

        default:
          target.removeClass('edgehandles-target');
          break; // don't add anything
        }
      }
```

Thanks,

Umbolt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [classes](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-edgehandles#classes) you can use in your stylesheet for this purpose.  They will take on the style specified in the stylesheet, regardless of when they are created -- similar to CSS stylesheets in HTML.

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for your answer. I will try to use classes as you suggest. But at first sight they refer to nodes and not to edges. Am I wrong? As I wrote in my message, I tryed to apply a style to specific edges (with a specific source), but it only altered existing edges, and no added ones.

Comment: And my other question: is the added edges data stored somewhere? In the elements.edges array? How can I have access to it so that I can add class and trigger events when they are created?

Comment: I found a partial answer to my questions: added edges from a specific source may be styled in the style section using a specific selector : {selector: 'edge[source = "I"]', css: {'line-color': 'red',}}. this led me to the conclusion that the added edges do merge with existing edges.